# to be global, or not to be

Tags: julia, global-variables, pass-by-reference, global

in Julia 1.6.1 [VScode 1.57.1 with Julia Extension 1.2.5] :
two trivial functions, two variables, one being `g1` (of type {Int64}) and the other `g2` (of type Vector{Int64} obviously). the enormously elaborate code on a Proust'ian scale in full is :

```
function set_g1(_a)
    _a = 0
end

function set_g2(_a)
    _a[length(_a)] = _a[begin]
end

g1 = 279
g2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

set_g1(g1)
set_g2(g2)

println(g1)
println(g2)
```

-- output :

```
279
[1, 2, 3, 1]
```

that's it. `g1` is passed on to `set_g1()` *'by value'* only and, of course, not *'by reference'* -- as Pascal'ians might put it

but `g2` isn't ?   but then it is what exactly ?

functionally it might well be a 'global' variable (tho not declared as such and that 'global' declaration would anyway be required in a function if it were meant to be a global var. it's doesn't matter).
nevermind local/gobal, `set_g2` in any event acts on `g2` by reference -- in effect.

'logical optics', so to speak, suffering from myopia here ?

however, me is myopic so perhaps it's me ..
and then one has to live with one's deficits, ' tries to cope and this *'by reference'*-behaviour does come in quite handy (given i have to deal with -- tho not liking it a bit -- loads of global variables)

but then i can't figure out how to pass `g1` on to `set_g1()` *'by reference'* [still like that antiquated Pascal method; but passing the var on and then, once functionally digested, returning it, visuo-logically looks not quite myopic, it looks somewhat clumsy]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set_g2` does *not* work "by reference" in your terminology, no.  In the body of the function, you are not changing `_a` -- you are changing its contents.

"By reference" is like: you give me an apple; I take another apple and give it back to you.  What happens in `set_g2`, though, is: you give me a box of apples.  I swap one one of the apples and give you back the box.  I didn't change the box.

You *can* pass values by reference, though, by wrapping them in the `Ref` type (which behaves like a rank zero array, almost like a pointer):

```
function set_g1!(_a::Ref{Int})
    _a[] = 0
end

g1 = Ref(234)
set_g1(g1)
@assert g1[] == 0
```

Locality does not have anything to do with it; by-reference is about values, not names.  (Also, you are not even shadowing anything.)

Comment: thanks for your coments. in particular your wrapping-hint is very helpfull to me.