# In Julia, after A = B, changing elements of B will modify A as well. Is it so?

Tags: julia

While reading Julia documentation in the section "Noteworthy differences from C/C++":

"Julia arrays are not copied when assigned to another variable. After A = B, changing elements of B will modify A as well. Updating operators like += do not operate in-place, they are equivalent to A = A + B which rebinds the left-hand side to the result of the right-hand side expression."

But I tried this, it is not happening i.e. changing B is not changing A. (I tried with 2x2 Matrix)

Can someone explain what this para means?

i tried the following code:

```
julia> m=Array(zeros(2,2))
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> k=m
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> k
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0

julia> m=Array(ones(2,2))
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.0  1.0
 1.0  1.0

julia> k
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0
```

Comment: `m=Array(ones(2,2))` does not *modify* the object assigned to `m`, it assigns a completely new object to it. That's not going to reflect on the other object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating copies in Julia with = operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002572/creating-copies-in-julia-with-operator) Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68193719/1346276?

Comment: Yeah it answered my question partially.

Comment: https://sylvaticus.github.io/IntroSPMLJuliaCourse/dev/01_-_JULIA1_-_Basic_Julia_programming/0102-types_and_objects.html#Mutability-property-of-Julia-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is explained

```
changing elements of B will modify A as well
```

So you can use the dotted version of assignment to change elements:

```
julia> m .= Array(ones(2,2))
```